# Auto add all files in the folder

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Following part includes a single file but I would like to include all files in the folder which matches with *.log.  Is there a way to make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE root
[
<!ENTITY log SYSTEM "Log.log">
]>
<root>
&log;
</root>
```

## *.log

There is no root element in log files.

> not even `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and/or xslt link like `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>` each file has 1000+ records like below

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="a54221e2-ad37-434a-8f0d-101f7abc2221" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test21</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="d30741c2-da73-434a-8f0d-101f7ceb2228" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test24</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning a problem that this would be the best method to solve. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Is each `.log` file a well-formed document in itself? Can you use Saxon 9, an XSLT 2.0 processor? Then you could write an XSLT stylesheet making use of the `collection` function to pull in all `.log` files and create a single file containing all content. But it would not use entity references to the files, it would include them directly inline.

Comment: @bjimba well it is long story short, I have bunch of entity xml log files and can not edit those.  Also I do not have control over environment so I can not write server side code neither.  I want to display log files which are not static (they have timestamp in file) anyway, I'm asking how to achieve this in XML/XSLT part, please feel free to add answer for that if you have any.  Thank you for your attention

Comment: @MartinHonnen I just updated the question with more details, please let me know if I can describe it in more details.  Unfortunately I have no control over the environment (even I believe it will be mostly IIS) and the only way to access the initial file will be via browser.  Thank you for your time and attention